# keypad hides half of the edittext view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-keypad

i used below layout . i am getting keypad hides issues on edittext view. it hides half of the edittext.i have used adjustpan in androidmanifest for the activity but could not fix the problem. please let me know if anyone know about any solution for this issue.

```
<i>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollviewid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_left_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_left_right" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutonechild"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin" >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/textviewone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"                  
                    android:contentDescription="image"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/str_takeviewone"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    custom:fontAssetName="@string/font_roboto_light" />

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/textviewsecond"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/top_margin"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/select_view_btn"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewone"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    custom:fontAssetName="@string/font_roboto_light" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_view_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_button_06_arrow_down"
                    android:onClick="onclickimagetakebtn" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/includelayoutone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layoutonechild"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"               
                layout="@layout/payment_error_layout" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayoutone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/includelayoutone"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_double_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.xxx.CoverFlow
                    android:id="@+id/carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_amount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutone"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@color/tabstrip"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rellayout_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/field_output_methods" >

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/amounttypeid"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:contentDescription="image"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                        android:text="@string/str_amount"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                      />

                    <TextView

                        android:id="@+id/amounttypetextid"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/amounttypeid"
                        android:text="@string/str_amount"
                        android:textColor="@color/White"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/amountId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/rellayout_amount"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_half_negative"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rellayout_amount"
                    android:background="@drawable/username_password"
                    android:digits="0123456789."
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:gravity="right|center"
                    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right_screen"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </EditText>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relatvivechildtwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_amount"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/textviewfour"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/field_output_07_paym_methods"
                    android:contentDescription="image"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/str_sendmoneyto"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    />

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/textviewfive"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/top_margin"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/select_view_btn"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textviewfour"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                   />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/send_view_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_button_06_arrow_down"
                    android:onClick="onClicksendViewBtn" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayoutchildtwo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relatvivechildtwo"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_double_margin"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                 <com.xxx.CoverFlow
                    android:id="@+id/sendcarousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutchildtwo"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@color/loyalty_tabstrip"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/datetextid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/field_output_methods"
                    android:contentDescription="image"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/str_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                   />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dateId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/datetextid"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_half_negative"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datetextid"
                    android:background="@drawable/username_password"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="right|center"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLength="50"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right_screen"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >
                </EditText>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_decs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_date"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
                android:background="@color/tabstrip"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/descid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/field_output_methods"
                    android:contentDescription="image"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/str_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:visibility="visible"
 />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/descId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="@+id/descid"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_half_negative"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/descid"
                    android:background="@drawable/username_password"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                      android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
                    android:gravity="right|center"
                    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                    android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                    android:maxLength="50"                 
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right_screen"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white_gray"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_dummy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_decs"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/top_double_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
                android:background="@color/tabstrip"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/dateid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/field_output_07_paym_methods"
                    android:contentDescription="image"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/str_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
               />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_dummy1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout_dummy"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/top_double_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
                android:background="@color/loyalty_tabstrip"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <TextView

                    android:id="@+id/dummytext"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:background="@drawable/field_outpu_paym_methods"
                    android:contentDescription="image"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
                    android:text="@string/str_desc"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                     />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_two"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         android:background="@color/brown"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <Button

            android:id="@+id/btnProc"
            style="@style/ButtonSelect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottom_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/right_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/top_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/button_disable"
            android:onClick="onBtn"
            android:text="@string/str_prc"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
 />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout> </i>
```

Comment: This link can help you for your answer 


  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1109108/1237420

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

//  or play with two combination like

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
```

in your AndroidManifest file for more information check the Activity's [windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) attribute

Comment: i tried with adjustresize as well but it does not work in the above layout.

Comment: i update my answer , use combination of two property